# $\Psi:G/N \to (\mathbb R^+,\times)$ with $aN \mapsto x$ is isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Assume $G=\left\{a+ib\in\mathbb{C} \mid a+ib \ne 0 \right\}$ is a multiplicative group and $N=\left\{a+ib \mid a^2+b^2=1\right\}$,then show that the quotient $G/N$ is isomorphic to the group $(\mathbb R^+,\times)$.

I guess we need to show that there is an isomorphism $\Psi:G/N \to (\mathbb R^+,\times)$ with $aN \mapsto x$

But for example how will we show that the function is homomorphism?
As I know if $N \trianglelefteq G$ then for $a_1N,a_2N \in G/N :(a_1N)(a_2N)=a_1a_2N$.

If we show that $N \trianglelefteq G$ then: $$\Psi(a_1N)=\Psi(a_2N)$$

$$\Psi(a_1N)\Psi(a_2N)^{-1}=1$$
$$\Psi(a_1N)\Psi(a_2^{-1}N)=1$$
$$\Psi(a_1a_2^{-1}N)=1$$
However we first need to show thet the function is homomorphism.

But does that help? Or maybe the mapping is not useful?

Comment: Consider the map $G\rightarrow \mathbb R^+$ by the Standard Norm. Do you know the first isomorphism theorem?

Comment: Try $z\mapsto z\bar{z}$.

Comment: the idea is try to construct a homomorphism from $G$ to $\mathbb R^+$ and show that it has kernel $N$ and is surjective. Then the first isomorphism gives you the result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115897/discussion-between-august-liu-and-45465).

Answer (score 2):

> (First Isomorphism Theorem)
> Let $G,H$ be groups and $f:G\rightarrow H$ be a homomorphism. If $f$ is surjective, then $G/{\ker f}$ is isomorphic to $H$.

**Hint:**

Define $f:G\rightarrow \Bbb{R}^+$ by $$a+ib\mapsto a^2+b^2$$
where $a+ib\in G$.
(i) Show that $f$ is a homomorphism.
(ii) Show that $f$ is surjective.
(iii) Show that $\ker f=N$.
Then by the First Isomorphism Theorem, we have $G/N\cong \Bbb{R}^+$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Do you mean the binary operation of $H$? I do assume that $G=\{a+ib:a,b\in \Bbb{R},(a,b)\neq (0,0)\}$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician He is clearly using the $G$ from the original question. For a general group, the definition would not make sense anyway.

Comment: @ancientmathematician I thought for any positive real $r$, $\sqrt{r}+0i$ will be mapped to $r$?

Comment: I see now that my understanding of what $G$ is is not yours. I should have realised that what the OP wrote is defective, and that your decoding of the question at least makes it true. I will delete all my comments later.